# VGG16 extremely low accuracy on acne grading

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to build an ance grading classifier with 3 classes (Level 0, Level 1, Level 2). I do not have a lot of images in the dataset (around 500 in each class). Therefore I used the VGG16 pre-trained model. However, the accuracy is really low (~0.33) and barely increased along with the training.

```
# Load VGG16 model
vgg_model = VGG16(weights="imagenet", 
                  include_top=False, 
                  input_tensor=Input(shape=(224,224,3)))
vgg_model.summary()

#make the model layers untrainable
for layer in vgg_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# Add output layer
output_model = vgg_model.output
output_model = layers.Dropout(0.25)(output_model)
output_model = layers.Flatten()(output_model)
output_model = layers.Dense(128,activation="relu")(output_model)
output_model = layers.Dropout(0.5)(output_model)
output_model = layers.Dense(3,activation="softmax")(output_model)

vggmodel = models.Model(inputs=vgg_model.input, outputs=output_model)

vggmodel.summary()


# Image augmentation on training set
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range = 40,
    width_shift_range = 0.2,
    height_shift_range = 0.2,
    shear_range = 0.15,
    rescale = 1./255,
)

# only rescale on validation set
validate_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255
)

#set size of batches of data to 64
batch_size = 64
#resizing to 224x224
target_size = (224, 224)

# initialize the training data augmentation object
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=training_path, class_mode="categorical",
                                                  batch_size=batch_size, target_size=target_size, color_mode='rgb', shuffle= True)
validation_generator = validate_datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=validation_path, class_mode="categorical",
                                                  batch_size=batch_size, target_size=target_size, color_mode='rgb', shuffle= True)

vggmodel.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=SGD(0.01),metrics=["accuracy"])

earlystopping = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor ="val_loss",  
                                        mode ="min", patience = 2,  
                                        restore_best_weights = True) 

vggmodel.fit(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=int(1166/batch_size), epochs= 100,
                        validation_data=validation_generator, validation_steps=5, callbacks=[earlystopping])
```

I have also tried building my own model but the performance is similar.

```
input_shape = (224,224,3)
cnn_model = models.Sequential()
cnn_model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu',
                               input_shape=input_shape))
cnn_model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu',
                                input_shape=input_shape))
cnn_model.add(layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2)))
cnn_model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu',
                                input_shape=input_shape))
cnn_model.add(layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2)))
cnn_model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))
cnn_model.add(layers.Flatten())
cnn_model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
cnn_model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
cnn_model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
cnn_model.summary()

cnn_model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=SGD(0.01),metrics=["accuracy"])


earlystopping = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor ="val_loss",  
                                        mode ="min", patience = 2,  
                                        restore_best_weights = True) 

cnn_model.fit(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=int(1248/batch_size), epochs= 15,
                        validation_data=validation_generator, validation_steps=2)
```

What did I do wrong? Sorry, I am a beginner :/

Comment: Which accuracy is low? Train or Validation? Also can you share your loss values?

Comment: both of them are low, training accuracy is ~0.33 and validation accuracy is ~0.37

Comment: How did you come up with this? `steps_per_epoch=int(1248/batch_size)`

Comment: 1248 is the number of training images. Any better suggestion?

Comment: What are the loss values? It can be related to the learning rate and optimizer. Maybe switch to 'adam' ? Also in your 2nd model, you passed input shape every time, one is enough I think.

Comment: You can also try adding some convolutions before flattening in the first model.

Comment: Loss value is similar as below for each epoch.                   
Epoch 8/100
18/18 [==============================] - 638s 35s/step - accuracy: 0.3521 - loss: 1.0987 - val_accuracy: 0.3375 - val_loss: 1.0978

Comment: I tried multiple ways such as increasing or decreasing the layers and also using adam as optimizer but no matter how I modify it the accuracy is similar (~0.3x)...

Comment: Get a layer's output from VGG using get_layer('layer_name').output after it try adding some convolutions. Let me know if that helps or not

Comment: Also try to reduce your batch size to 32 - 16.

Comment: I used this kaggle dataset and did image augmentation to fix the data imbalance problem fyi. https://www.kaggle.com/rutviklathiyateksun/acne-grading-classificationdataset

Comment: tried adding three conv2D layers, would that be too much? Also, I reduced the batch size to 32. Accuracy seems going up :) but still takes some time to see the final result.

Comment: The dataset is very small, it is really difficult get the desired accuracy. Add or remove depending on the behaviour of the model. Also I think SGD(0.01) is not good choice for the optimizer. Try Adam(0.0003). And do not specify validation_steps since you have limited amount of data.

Comment: Yes, I also changed the optimizer. Tried Adam(0.001) for the last round and got around 0.5 before earlystopping stopped. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Turns out the best I got is around 0.57 training acc and 0.54 for validation accuracy. Is there any way to push it further?

Comment: I inspected the dataset, it is imbalanced and contains inadequate number of images. So using opencv to augmenting images might be helpful rather than using Keras image augmention. Also you can try Resnets. And what are your expectations about accuracy? Accuracy is not a good metric in that case, you need to look up precision recall and f1 scores to get a reliable evaluation of the model.

Comment: Yes I did use opencv to do image augmentation such that all three classes would have ~540 images, should I do more? But would it not generalize well as the level 2 only has ~130 images? I was hoping to push the accuracy up to ~ 60-70%

Comment: Try to make your dataset balanced by augmenting class 3 more. Also that's a problem in ML, if you have limited data like this, it is hard to generalize. Augmention is the biggest factor that can help generalizing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the max-pooling layer, instead of a flatten layer.
2. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43720817/how-many-epochs-does-it-take-to-train-vgg-16) user had to reduce learning rate to 0.001, to get acceptable results.
3. Use smaller dropout rate. .2, .3 for example.
4. 33% is just random guessing. Print some images and see that their labels are correct.
5. Check the output of your model on some sample image. Is it too close to 1 or 0 in some columns? Does it seem just random?

Do these and you might catch the bug.